# manipulate date from Excel to MySQl using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I'm using PHP I'm trying to import date from Excel document which has the format 31/12/2014 but when I use this code

```
$date_debut = $data->sheets[0]["cells"][$x][1];
echo date('Y-m-l', strtotime($date_debut));
$date_middle = str_replace('/', '-', $date_debut);
  $date = strtotime($date_middle); 
$date_facture = date('Y-m-d', $date);
```

I get 1970-01-01. Ive tried many solutions but I can't get rif of this issue.
I tried also

`$date_facture = date_create($date_debut)->format('Y-m-d');`

But I still have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `DateTime::createFromFormat`

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '31/12/2014' );
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: Yes i4ve tried this code also but I get the error " Call to a member function format() on a non-object "

Answer (score 0):

in SQL

```
$date_debut = '31/12/2014';
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO ma_table SET mon_champ_date = STR_TO_DATE('$date_debut', '%d/%m/%Y'), ...");
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the following worked for me:

> $date_time = $rowVal[3]; // This was the date formatted in excel as dd/mm/yy H:i:s.
>
> $date_time = strtotime($date_time); // strtotime apparently understood this format.
>
> $date_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date_time); // use the strtotime version with date().